# Extract random slice from tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an input tensor of shape (1, 512, 512, 32) generated in a tensorflow queue reader by

```
batch_input, batch_output = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, capacity=3 * BATCH_SIZE + min_queue_examples,
                                                    enqueue_many=True, min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples, num_threads=16)
#BATCH_SIZE = 1
```

I would like to select a random slice on the 4th dimension of this output tensor such that each time a new batch is called, a new random slice is also taken. I have tried the following with `numpy`

```
rand_slice_ind = np.random.randint(0, 32)
slice_begin = tf.constant([0, 0, 0, rand_slice_ind])
slice_input = tf.slice(batch_input, begin = slice_begin, size = [BATCH_SIZE, height, width, 1])
```

However this returns the same value for `rand_slice_ind` each time. I assume this has something to do with using a non tensorflow object that is being generated outside of the graph.

I have also tried something with `tf.random_uniform` along the lines of:

```
rand_slice_ind = tf.random_uniform([], minval=0, maxval=depth, dtype=tf.int32)    
slice_begin = tf.Variable([tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32), tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32), tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32), rand_slice_ind])
```

But this is causing issues with the gradient calculations. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to achieve this using [gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather):

```
slice_length = 128
data_length = data.shape[your_axis]
max_offset = data_length - slice_length
random_offset = tf.random.uniform((), minval=0, maxval=max_offset, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64)
slice_indices = tf.range(0, slice_length, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64)
random_slice = tf.gather(data, slice_indices + random_offset, axis=your_axis)
```